# Java Jbutton смена иконки

Tags: java, swing

Не меняется иконка у кнопки, при нажатии. В чем может быть проблема?

```
JToggleButton Start = new JToggleButton("", false);

    Start.setIcon(new 
ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/AC/drop_logo2.png")));
    Start.setBounds(97, 46, 96, 91);
    Start.setFocusable(false);
    Start.setBorderPainted(false);

    Start.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    frmAnticheat.getContentPane().add(Start);

    Start.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            String icon = (Start.isSelected()) ? "/AC/drop_logo2.png" : 
                                                      "/AC/logogo.png";
                Start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource(icon)));

            }
        });
```

Comment: Проверьте, загружается ли просто 2е изображение, вполне возможно что проблема в его названии

Comment: действительно что-то с картинкой было, хотя путь правильный, но замена ее помогла. спасибо